# meta keywords characterset

Tags: character-encoding, meta-tags

On my site [sinj.com.hr](http://www.sinj.com.hr) I have croatian diacritic letters which I encode to utf-8 html entities. For example,

> Obiteljski liječnici, na području koje
>   pokriva sinjska ispostava Nastavnog
>   zavoda za javno zdravstvo, danas su
>   počeli s cijepljenjem protiv sezonske
>   gripe. Dodajmo kako cjepivo protiv
>   sezonske gripe nije otporno na virus
>   nove pandemijske H1N1 gripe.
>   Cijepljenje protiv svinjske gripe
>   počet će u prosincu

in html is printed like this:

```
Obiteljski lije&#269;nici, na podru&#269;ju koje pokriva sinjska ispostava Nastavnog zavoda za javno zdravstvo, danas su po&#269;eli s cijepljenjem protiv sezonske gripe. Dodajmo kako cjepivo protiv sezonske gripe nije otporno na virus nove pandemijske H1N1 gripe. Cijepljenje protiv svinjske gripe po&#269;et &#263;e u prosincu
```

I wonder, how should this string be printed in meta tag? I'm asking this because some search engines in their results show utf-8 entity instead of character. In google it works fine, but [Yahoo](http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0geutKcp_RKCGsB04dXNyoA?p=sinj&fr2=sb-top&fr=yfp-t-701&sao=0) doesn't show it correctly (if link is not good, try to search for "sinj")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not much you can do.  Yahoo search engine is the one at fault here.  You could try encoding the characters in UTF-8 directly, though, since you have declared the `content-type` meta tag correctly.

Comment: Also declaring the charset in the content-type http header might help.

Comment: Right.  It isn't declared.  That might be the problem with the Yahoo search engine.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Currently, this is what I have: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"></meta>

Comment: Yes, that's the http-equiv tag in the HTML file, but you need the Web server to send an equivalent header as well.  That would be something to set up in your Apache configuration.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset